# NodeJS email-templates promise hangs the execution

Tags: node.js, promise, email-templates

I'm losing my eyes on this.

I've a function called sendEmail:

```
sendEmail() {

        let emailAddress = "test@domain.tld";

        const email = new Email(
            {
                send: true,
                preview: false,
                message: {
                    from: 'sender@domain.tld',
                    to: emailAddress
                },
                transport: 
                {
                    host: 'smtp.domain.tld',
                    auth: {
                       user: 'user',
                       pass: 'pass'
                    }
                },
                i18n:
                {
                    locales: ['en-GB', 'en-US', 'it-IT'],
                    directory: path.join(__dirname, '../../emails/locales')
                }
            }
        );

        return email.send({
            template: 'map',
            locals: {
                locale: status.locale
            }
        }).then(console.log);
    }
```

It returns the Promise that should be returned by email.send (don't know if this is true!).

In my test.js code, I tried almost everything, like this:

Promise.all([sendEmail()]).then(() =>console.log("Done"));

And I see in the console the log from email.send and the final "Done", but the program is hanged. It doesn't close.

Why? I don't get this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you need a `Promise.all` as you are only doing one thing.

Regarding node process not being exiting or in hung state, there could be multiple reasons for that. Like open db connections, open handle etc. Node is capabale enough to see if everything is finished and exit the code. You could manually call `process.exit` after console log to exit but ideally you shouldn't require this.

so I would also suggest to use `https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running` package to find any open handles. You need to add it where you expect your program to termninate. So in your case it will be like this

```
const log = require("why-is-node-running");

sendEmail()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Done");
    log();
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the package. I only want to underline that that is the running code. No different packages or stuff, no db connections at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the i18n part is blocking the whole stuff.

I don't know exactly why, but removing that part, everything is working correctly.